# Is it easy to check if two matrices define the same quadratic form over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Given two $\ell \times \ell$ symmetric matrices, is there an easy way to check if they define the same quadratic form over $\mathbb{Z}$ (up to a change of basis)?

In particular, among other examples, I am interested in the following two matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix} 4 &  2 &  2 &  4 &  4 \\
2 &  4 &  2 &  4 &  4 \\
2 &  2 &  4 &  4 &  4 \\
4 &  4 &  4 & 16 & 12 \\
4 &  4 &  4 & 12 & 16   \end{pmatrix} \qquad , \qquad 
\begin{pmatrix}
8 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
6 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
6 & 6 & 8 & 6 & 6 \\
6 & 6 & 6 & 8 & 6 \\
6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I actually conjecture that they don't, so even a partial criteria (for instance an invariant common to all equivalent matrices) would suffice.

Comment: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/overview/2/17/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integer coefficient quadratic forms, equivalence is
$$ P^T A P = B,   $$
the requirement being that $P$ have all integer elements and determinant $\pm 1.$
So, one invariant is determinant. Your pair have different determinants, those being $2048$ and $512.$

The second thing is, for positive definite forms (these both are) to find the minimum, that is the smallest integer that cn be written as $x^T Ax$ where the column vector $x$ has integer elements, not all zero. That will take me several minutes.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I did not know, the "over $\mathbb{Z}$" part.

Answer (score 0):

Two such matrices $M,N$ define the same quadratic form if and only if they are equal.

For the proof of "only if", consider the standard basis of row vectors $e_1,\ldots,e_\ell$, consider the two basis vectors $e_i,e_j$. The evaluation of the $M$ quadratic form on the those two basis vectors yields the number $e_i M e_j^T = M_{ij}$; and the evaluation of the $N$ quadratic form yields $e_i N e_j^T = N_{ij}$; so if the two quadratic forms are "the same" --- i.e. if they are equal --- then $M_{ij}=N_{ij}$ for all choice of $i,j$.

Comment: Okay, but I have not fixed the basis here. I meant "up to a change of basis", sorry if it was unclear.